# How to check whether a string's name in Java is the same as an integer's name?

Tags: java, string, integer, converters

For example, if the user enters "sword", the integer variable sword should change its value from 0 to 1. 
If the user enters "boots", the integer variable for boots should change from 0 to 1. I know I can do a manual if statement for each of these articles I want to check, but is there any possible way to check the string entered and change the respective variable's value without making an if statement for each article?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your information inside of a map instead.  When a user enters a string that you key off of (sword, boots, etc), then update its value.

```
public class DataClass {
    Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void addValueToData(String key) {
        if(!data.containsKey(key)) {
            data.put(key, 0);
        } else {
            data.put(key, data.get(key) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using reflection ([Java Tutorials - Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)) but a very inefficent and slow way. You should consider unsing a switch case statement or even better, a map:

- [Java Tutorials for Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)
- [Oracle Docs - Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)